# How to close port 445 (Apple Time Capsule smbd)

Tags: firewalls, smb, apple

My default configuration of Apple Time Capsule has port 445 (Apple Time Capsule smbd) open to the world. Online port scanners (shodan/detectify.com) show me that this. What's a bit worrying is the version showing "SMB Version: 1" and I don't need to share files with the world over SMB.

Is it ok to disable this and how would I do that ?

Can Airport Utility do this ?

Comment: You have essentially two options: Configure Time Capsule to not offer this (which should be asked over at [apple.se]), or configure your firewall to not allow any incoming traffic at TCP/455.

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust random devices to be secure.

Instead, implement a firewall between 'the internet' and your device, and make sure to block this unrequired traffic at the firewall level. Apple have discontinued the product, and according to at least [one chat thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8642526) there isn't a firmware upgrade to disable this, nor will one be forth coming.

As a slight aside, this is why people often choose to implement their own solutions rather than using a off the shelf one. Once the manufacturer stops supporting it, you're left with something that'll never be more secure than at that moment. A ticking time bomb if you will.